# Android + FCM not receiving notifications

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm integrating Firebase FCM to my pre-existing Android app.

I connected the app to my firebase account and project using the Android Studio (2.3.3) assistant.

I use the Firebase console to send notifications. I didn't actually implemented the rest api.

Sometimes everything works fine. Sometimes it take ages to receive the notification (even 1 day after). Sometimes notifications never arrive.

I linked the Firebase project to Google Play Developer console using the sender id, in order to use the "FCM Diagnostics" in GPD.

The last notification I sent, (more than 1 hour ago) is marked as completed on FCM console, but never received, and FCM Diagnostics does not show any entry for around the hour I sent.

Troubleshooting this problem is very difficult.

Anyone has experienced similar situatuon and can help me?

**EDIT:** Android studio 2.3.3 adds com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging dependency with version number 10.0.1. However, the latest release is 11.0.2. This morning I updated the gradle reference to the latest. I'll experiment with this version.

Comment: I have had the same bitter experience with firebase I resorted to using one signal. It offers a better dashboard to control notifications.

Comment: I also experiencing it today, yesterday was fine tho